# Windows Explorer Integration in TortoiseHG

Tags: tortoisehg

Is there a way to integrate Windows Explorer in the TortoiseHg workbench?

Things like:

- Right click a file in the workbench --> open in Windows Explorer
- Right click a file in the workbench --> see the contextmenu you would see when right clicking the file in Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseHg has already had this feature. In the TortoiseHg, select a repo > right click > `Explore`.